# Python adding list as a key in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary where the key is date ,
In my case each date is a list like this : `[2012, 5, 25]`.

This is the code that I have which reads from a csv file into dictionary.
This code is given I can't change it :

```
def read_profiles(r_file_name):
    """Reads the file profiles-full.csv into a dictionary where the key is the users id 
    and the value is a dictionary with users fields "public", "compl_percent", "gender", 
    "region", "last_login", "age", "body". In addition to this dictionary, the function 
    returns the list of all users that have 0 completion percentage."""
    users = {}
    noinfo_users = []
    with open(r_file_name, 'rb') as csvfile:
        linereader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for line in linereader:
            profile = {}
            data_fields = ("public", "compl_percent", "gender", "region",
                                     "last_login", "age", "body")
            for field, raw_data in zip(data_fields, line[1:]):
                if field == "compl_percent" and int(raw_data) == 0:
                    noinfo_users.append(int(line[0]))

                if raw_data == "null":
                    profile[field] = None
                elif field == "body":
                    profile[field] = raw_data
                elif field == "last_login": #<=== reading last_login
                    profile[field] = map(int, raw_data.split("-"))
                elif field == "region":
                    profile[field] = map(int, raw_data.split(";"))
                else:
                    profile[field] = int(raw_data)

            users[int(line[0])] = profile
    return users, noinfo_users
```

And this is the content of the csv file, corresponding to this pattern:

```
"public", "compl_percent", "gender", "region",                  "last_login", "age", "body"**
231702, 1, 60, 0, 1;1;21, 2012-05-15, 0, 171 cm;58 kg
```

This is how an element in profiles dictionary looks like:

```
1492433: {'body': '160 cm;54 kg', 'compl_percent': 78, 'gender': 0, 'region': [1, 10, 6], 'age': 36, 'last_login': [2012, 5, 25], 'public': 1}
```

This is my function:

```
def getStrongConnectedForAttr(user,edges,profiles,attr):
    result = dict()
    if user in edges:
        userFriends = edges.get(user)
        for friend in userFriends:
            if isBidirectional(edges,user,friend) == 2:
                if friend in profiles:
                    friendAttr = (profiles.get(friend))[str(attr)]
                    if attr == "last_login":
                        #friendAttr = '-'.join(map(str, friendAttr))
                        friendAttr = tuple(friendAttr)
                    if friendAttr in result: #<===== error
                        result[friendAttr] = result.get(friendAttr) + 1
                    else:
                        result[friendAttr] = 1
        return sorted(result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    else:
        return result
```

It takes profiles as one of the parameters, and builds an empty dictionary.
In the line `if friendAttr in result:` I get the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I tried searching the web for solution and I found many, especially here on Stack Overflow, and as you can see I tried many solutions, one to convert the list to tuple, or join the list to string.
But none of them worked.

Comment: Just convert to a tuple: `tuple(friendAttr)`

Comment: Turning your key into a tuple certainly should have worked; but why are you doing it *conditionally*?

Comment: As the message says, a key in the dictionary needs to be hashable (https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) - Since it is a date, you can stringify it and store it as the key.

Comment: @Peter Wood you can see in my function i tried friendAttr = tuple(friendAttr)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters sorry i dont understand what are you referring to

Comment: @ karthikr  also you can see that i tired that #friendAttr = '-'.join(map(str, friendAttr))

Comment: @Epsilon You only convert it to a tuple if `attr == "last_login"`

Comment: because that when my key is a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only turning the `login_attr` values to a tuple, but forgetting about the `region` attribute. It is *those* values that still throw the exception.

You are only testing for `login_attr` here:

```
if attr == "last_login":
    friendAttr = tuple(friendAttr)
```

Rather than turn your values to tuples there, just *store tuples* when reading the file.

Replace

```
elif field == "last_login": #<=== reading last_login
    profile[field] = map(int, raw_data.split("-"))
elif field == "region":
    profile[field] = map(int, raw_data.split(";"))
```

with

```
elif field == "last_login":
    profile[field] = tuple(map(int, raw_data.split("-")))
elif field == "region":
    profile[field] = tuple(map(int, raw_data.split(";")))
```

Comment: would it work when even my key is a number ? because as you can see in profile element i have all sorts of things , lists , numbers ....

Comment: @Epsilon: right, you can always *test* for a list first, or not store lists in the first place.

Comment: @Epsilon: Updated with a better approach; turn your values into tuples *earlier*, and handle both.